# Solr on heroku does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, solr, production-environment

I have just deployed my app on Heroku. I have access to home however when I create an account I have the error "we're sorry but something were wrong". In the heroku console there are the following lines :

```
2013-07-25T14:43:57.205734+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-25T14:43:57.326077+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-25T14:43:57.326077+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:36:in `create'
2013-07-25T14:43:57.326077+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - {:data=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><add><doc><field name=\"id\">User 23</field><field name=\"type\">User</field><field name=\"type\">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name=\"class_name\">User</field><field name=\"nom_text\">julien</field><field name=\"email_text\">julien@resenders.com</field></doc></add>", :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, :method=>:post, :params=>{:wt=>:ruby}, :query=>"wt=ruby", :path=>"update", :uri=>#<URI::HTTP:0x007f987b4c48a0 URL:http://localhost:8080/solr/update?wt=ruby>, :open_timeout=>nil, :read_timeout=>nil, :retry_503=>nil, :retry_after_limit=>nil}):
2013-07-25T14:43:57.337273+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2013-07-25T14:43:57.326077+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-25T14:43:57.326077+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-07-25T14:43:57.337273+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 850ms
2013-07-25T14:43:57.337273+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"???", "authenticity_token"=>"gdLt0F1TJi+GaFCe8sFFKRikXgAEEnW6DmIyPbLeCa4=", "user"=>{"nom"=>"julien", "email"=>"julien@resenders.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "resender"=>"0", "gang_id"=>"1", "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>"L", "last_name"=>"L"}}}, "commit"=>"Inscription"}
2013-07-25T14:43:57.337273+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.3ms)
2013-07-25T14:43:57.344954+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users host=www.resenders.com fwd="37.58.138.20" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=930ms status=500 bytes=643
```

I figured out the problem in local with "rake sunspot:solr:run" but even if "heroku run rake sunspot:solr:run" seems to work, it does not sort out this trouble on Heroku. How can I do ? Maybe with Websolr ? Thank you in advance guys !

Comment: `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused` is the server running?

Comment: Yes because I can go on the website (on production mode)

Comment: I am speaking about Solr.

Answer (score 0):

4 Suggestions:

- Be sure that your server is running
- Be sure that your routes are set correctly
- Add the websolr add on to your heroku stack --> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websolr
- Be sure to always remove personal data when pasting code to the internet

Comment: Websolr was indeed the solution ! Thank you